# All test classes failing upon deploying with "run local tests"

Tags: apex, unit-test, deployment

error shown:

```
    line -1, column -1: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation: Class classname: Invalid type: soapSforceCom200604Metadata.DeleteResult 
Stack Trace: null
```

says this for every single test class.

Comment: Are you deploying from Summer 18 sandbox to Spring 18Live?

Comment: Yes, I believe so, how could I double check

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199268&type=1

Comment: both sandboxes have api 43 available

Comment: It is complaining that some class (I would have expected to see it right after `classname:`) can't be compiled because `soapSforceCom200604Metadata.DeleteResult` can't be found. Does this class and the inner class of `DeleteResult` exist?